# WPF DataBinding with other Namespace/Class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I´m having problems with databinding using WPF. I have a Webservice(WCF) into a Windows Service App and a WPF App for control the service. In the WPF App, I builded a textbox where i want to receive Logs from the WebService.

At this moment i can send new data from the same namespace (WPF app) but when i send it from the (WCF app) using the instance of my data class, it dont reflect the new data in the textbox.

Here is my code:

> MainWindow.xaml

```
...
   <Grid Name="grid" Margin="0,0,346.6,4">
       <TextBox Name="Log" Text="{Binding Path=LogText}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" IsReadOnly="True" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" Margin="30.8,35,-325.8,0" Height="303" Grid.RowSpan="2" Width="295"/>
   </Grid>
...
```

> MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
                InitializeComponent();
                grid.DataContext = Logs.Instance;
                ...
    }

public class Logs : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
           private static Logs instance;

           private Logs() { }

           public static Logs Instance
           {
              get 
              {
                 if (instance == null)
                 {
                     instance = new Logs();
                 }
                 return instance;
              }
           }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected void Notify(string propName)
            {
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
                }
            } 

            private string _LogText = "";

            public string LogText
            {
                get
                {
                    return _LogText;
                }
                set
                {
                    _LogText = value;
                    Notify("LogText");
                }
            }

            public void LogBinding(String text)
            {
                LogText = text + LogText;
            }
}
```

> WCF Webservice Send Text Call (Other Namespace)

```
Using "THE NAMESPACE OF WPF APP";

Logs.Instance.LogBinding("Some Text");
```

THANK YOU !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you have two separate applications which are running as separate processes. Static instances are not shared across processes even if they're the same class. You need to use some form of cross process communication to pass data from your Windows Service to your WPF app.

Comment: You´re Right!! my apps are running in separate processes !!! Thank you you clear my mind. So what you recommend for the communication: Something like Named Pipes??

Comment: Yes, Named Pipes can be a good way to go for this kind of situation.